# what is the USB HID code for the Compose key?

Tags: usb, keyboard, hid

I have a [programmable USB keyboard](http://www.trulyergonomic.com) for which I want to have a [Compose key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key), like some keyboards from the Digital Equipment Corporation had. I need to know the **USB HID code** for this key.

I also have [this list of USB HID codes](http://www.freebsddiary.org/APC/usb_hid_usages.php). The only occurrence of the word *Compose* is below section *LEDs* which i suppose can’t be assigned to a key – or at least won’t be recognized as a Compose key by any operating system.

I know that in X11 the key is called *Multi_key*. But there is no multi key in this USB HID codes list.

Any ideas? Which one could it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the X.org X11 server, `K_COMPOSE` is translated to `XK_Multi_key` in [`hw/dmx/input/lnx-keyboard.c:986`](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/tree/hw/dmx/input/lnx-keyboard.c#n986). However, in Linux `drivers/hid/hid-input.c`, there is no code that gets mapped to `KEY_COMPOSE`.

(From your table, I'd choose one of the "Keyboard International" codes if I had to pick an existing one.)

Comment: Ok, that’s what I feared it would be. Not supported. :-( I’ll do like you said. Thanks anyway.